# Authenticate the user on Azure AD using ADAL library from Android native app

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-android-sdk

We have a requirement where users should signin from Native apps(Android, iOS) without invoking Microsoft login web view window from the app. We have the sample code that demonstrates non-interactive authentication to Azure AD using a username & password from the .net console application.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless

sample code:

AuthenticationResult result = null;

```
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());

        string userName = "user@sample.onmicrosoft.com";
        string password = "Test@123";

        UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);

        result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(appResourceId, clientId, uc).Result;
```

The same way we are trying to achieve it in Android. First I would like to know whether it is possible to do the same in Android and if yes, can you please provide me some sample code so we can implement in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the answer is yes. And there is a same sample code in Java https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless. You need to follow the Java sample code and rewrite it using [`adal4android`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android), which maven repository is [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.aad/adal/1.11.0).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have cracked it.

Comment: Can you guide me on the same implementation in iOS?

Comment: @Sarva Just the same logic using Adal for different languages. It's adal for Object-C https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc. There isn't an existing sample code for iOS.

Comment: I still can not find the call where you have to add the username/password you get from the user (Android). Can you point me a bit more in the right direction?